# Where do the npm modules are stored?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am learning node.js.I have few questions

1. Where the npm modules are stored?

2.Is it a database?

3.Is internet required for installing node modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. npm modules are usually stored in the repository. It is a common way, but npm can install modules from an ordinary http server or git repository.
2. npmjs.org uses a database ([CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/)), but there are solutions that store modules in the filesystem without any database ([Sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia)).
3. Not always, but you have to get those modules from somewhere, right?

Answer (score 0):

npm modules are stored in npm registry https://npmjs.org/

If you install modules from public repository, you must have internet.

However, you can setup your private repository, see [this](https://npmjs.org/doc/registry.html#Can-I-run-my-own-private-registry) and [this](http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/how-to-create-a-private-npmjs-repository)